# Two line title in google chart api

Tags: html, charts, pie-chart

I am using Google chart api to create a pie chart.

What I want here is to display the title in two lines.

One is the actual title and below that some info in small text.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Last time I played with it (was, admittedly, a while ago) you had to split lines with a pipe (`|`)...

Comment: @BradChristie nope, just tried pipe, did not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just tried to get myself caught up on the API (guess they do this via javascript now and deprecated the image charts--good to know). Anyways...

There's a page on [Pie Chart options](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options), but nothing specific to per-line. You can split lines using `\n`, but you're stuck with a uniform styling (via `titleTextStyle`).

However, given the library outputs an SVG we have complete ability to manipulate the DOM after it's generated. Granted, I'm sure there's a fallback of some kind that google uses if SVG isn't supported, but if we *can* modify it, why not.

So, since the proof's in the pudding:

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate\nLast Night',
                 'titleTextStyle': {
                   'fontSize': '16'
                 },
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(chart_div);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  
  var heading = chart_div.getElementsByTagName('g')[0];
  if (heading){
    var title = heading.getElementsByTagName('text')[1];
    if (title){
      title.setAttribute('font-size', '10');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried this approach, but to no avail. [Are you able to guide me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869523/google-charts-api-2-line-title-with-smaller-text-underneath) what I might be doing wronh?

Comment: how would this work if it were a `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

Comment: @3kstc it's been years since ive touched this api. If you're still having issues I suggest creating a new SO question & ref what you've tried and relevant posts (inc this one) that didn't help resolve the issue. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I have a similar question with [google chart histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062674/google-charts-api-histogram-how-to-fuse-bars-and-change-x-ticks-to-integers), could you please kindly have a look?!