# How to stop font size defaulting after zooming in on a google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart API to create a time-line graph and want the strings underneath the title of the graph to continue to be at the same font size, irrespective of the graph being zoomed in or not.

**Question:**

After I zoom in into the graph the strings (`Average Event ...`, `line 3`)  underneath the title default to the original size, how can I make it so that when zoomed in, or after zooming in these lines (`Average Event ...`, `line 3`) continue to stay in the original text size

**Current Output:**

Before zooming:

[image]

After zooming:

[image]

**Ideal Output:**

[image]

**Relevant Research:**

I could not find any reference, or anyone who had a similar issue.

**MWE:**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date \& Time');
data.addColumn('number', "Triggered Events");
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRows([
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0), 0, ''],


 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 3, 41, 44), 0, ''],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 3, 41, 44), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 14m 57s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 03:41:44\nEnd Time: 05:56:41'],

 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 5, 56, 41), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 14m 57s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 03:41:44\nEnd Time: 05:56:41'],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 5, 56, 41), 0, ''],

 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 9, 40, 48), 0, ''],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 9, 40, 48), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 30m 17s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 09:40:48\nEnd Time: 12:11:05'],

 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 11, 5), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 30m 17s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 09:40:48\nEnd Time: 12:11:05'],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 11, 5), 0, ''],

 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 45, 57), 0, ''],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 45, 57), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 28m 9s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 12:45:57\nEnd Time: 15:14:06'],

 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 15, 14, 6), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 28m 9s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 12:45:57\nEnd Time: 15:14:06'],
 [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 15, 14, 6), 0, ''],

 [new Date(2022, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 0, '']
]);   //End data.addRows([])

var options = {
 title:'Generated 3 Events\nAverage Event Duration: 2h 24m 27s\nline 3',
 tooltip: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Lucida Console', fontSize: 12} },
 width: 1100,
 height: 500,
 lineWidth: 1,
 chartArea:{width: 900, height:150 },
 series: { 0: { color: '#188785', areaOpacity: 1.0}},
 legend: {position: 'none'},
 enableInteractivity: true,

 hAxis: {
  title: 'Date \& Time',
  titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
  slantedText:true,
  slantedTextAngle:90,
  gridlines: {color: 'none'},
  },  //End hAxis

 vAxis: {
  title: 'Events Triggered',
  titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
  viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 1},
  ticks: [{ v: 0, f: 'Event Off'}, {v: 1, f: 'Event On'}],
  gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }
  },  //End vAxis

 explorer: {
  actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
  axis: 'horizontal',
  keepInBounds: true,
  maxZoomIn: 20.0,
  },  //End explorer

 };  //End var options

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  // listen for chart ready event
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
// get label copy to change
var labelContent = options.title.split('\n');

// get chart labels
var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');

// loop chart title lines, beginning with second line
for (var l = 1; l < labelContent.length; l++) {
  // find chart label
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].textContent === labelContent[l]) {
      // reduce font size
      var currentFontSize = parseInt(labels[i].getAttribute('font-size'));
      labels[i].setAttribute('font-size', currentFontSize - 4);
      break;
    }
  }
}
  });

chart.draw(data, options);

}  //End drawChart()
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: After you zoom in, you'll need to click "Run code snippet" again to make the title appear in the correct format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the chart does not register a "zoom" event,
we'll need to use a `MutationObserver`
which will let us know anytime the chart changes.

```
// listen for changes to the chart
var observer = new MutationObserver(setTitle);
observer.observe(chart.getContainer(), {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

we'll create the `MutationObserver` during the `'ready'` event.
after saving the original font size.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date \& Time');
data.addColumn('number', "Triggered Events");
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRows([
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0), 0, ''],


  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 3, 41, 44), 0, ''],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 3, 41, 44), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 14m 57s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 03:41:44\nEnd Time: 05:56:41'],

  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 5, 56, 41), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 14m 57s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 03:41:44\nEnd Time: 05:56:41'],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 5, 56, 41), 0, ''],

  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 9, 40, 48), 0, ''],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 9, 40, 48), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 30m 17s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 09:40:48\nEnd Time: 12:11:05'],

  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 11, 5), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 30m 17s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 09:40:48\nEnd Time: 12:11:05'],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 11, 5), 0, ''],

  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 45, 57), 0, ''],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 12, 45, 57), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 28m 9s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 12:45:57\nEnd Time: 15:14:06'],

  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 15, 14, 6), 1, 'Event Duration: 2h 28m 9s\nMax Val: XYZ °C\nStart Time: 12:45:57\nEnd Time: 15:14:06'],
  [new Date(2021, 11, 31, 15, 14, 6), 0, ''],

  [new Date(2022, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 0, '']
]);   //End data.addRows([])

var options = {
  title:'Generated 3 Events\nAverage Event Duration: 2h 24m 27s\nline 3',
  tooltip: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Lucida Console', fontSize: 12} },
  width: 1100,
  height: 500,
  lineWidth: 1,
  chartArea:{width: 900, height:150 },
  series: { 0: { color: '#188785', areaOpacity: 1.0}},
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  enableInteractivity: true,

  hAxis: {
    title: 'Date \& Time',
    titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
    slantedText:true,
    slantedTextAngle:90,
    gridlines: {color: 'none'},
    },  //End hAxis

  vAxis: {
    title: 'Events Triggered',
    titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
    viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 1},
    ticks: [{ v: 0, f: 'Event Off'}, {v: 1, f: 'Event On'}],
    gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }
    },  //End vAxis

  explorer: {
    actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
    axis: 'horizontal',
    keepInBounds: true,
    maxZoomIn: 20.0,
    },  //End explorer

  };  //End var options

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

var origFontSize;

// listen for chart events
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  // save font size of chart label
  var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
  origFontSize = parseInt(labels[0].getAttribute('font-size')) - 4;
  setTitle();

  // listen for changes to the chart
  var observer = new MutationObserver(setTitle);
  observer.observe(chart.getContainer(), {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });
});

function setTitle() {
  // get label copy to change
  var labelContent = options.title.split('\n');

  // get chart labels
  var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');

  // loop chart title lines, beginning with second line
  for (var l = 1; l < labelContent.length; l++) {
    // find chart label
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      if (labels[i].textContent === labelContent[l]) {
        // reduce font size
        labels[i].setAttribute('font-size', origFontSize);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

chart.draw(data, options);

}  //End drawChart()
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: In one word - wow; in two - mind blown. Thank you!! <3 Also, how do you know all this, is it through experience, or is there a book you could recommend?

Comment: @3kstc I believe I have the most relevant sources concerning gVis and it pales in comparison to WhiteHat's answers, just bookmark his [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat)

Comment: @WhiteHat sorry, I was just in a state of awe and forgot!

Comment: no worries, thanks!! please let me know if I can help with anything...

Comment: @WhiteHat - :) I hope you wouldn't be cross with me, if I had just one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315954/how-to-generate-a-box-and-whisker-chart-using-the-google-charts-api-with-irregul)?

Comment: of course not, but that question has my head spinning. if it weren't for the intervals, adding the rows with different lengths wouldn't be a problem. we need the rows with lesser values to be shifted to the end, next to the interval columns. for instance, on Tuesday, after running through `getBoxPlotValues`, you have the original values, followed by three nulls, then the box plot values. we need the nulls to swap places with the original values. at least i think. I'll try again later...

Comment: @WhiteHat I've done a bunch of reading yesterday and couldn't find a way, so I've [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315954/how-to-generate-a-box-and-whisker-chart-using-the-google-charts-api-with-irregul) - I think it's relatively easier now...

Comment: @WhiteHat - I just have one very very last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448816/google-charts-title-alignment-and-font-size)  (I promise) very similar to this but for some reason I can't seem to get my head around this.